# how to omit in sails.js two or more sockets in sails.sockets.broadcast?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails.io.js

I need to know how to omit in sails.js two or more sockets in sails.sockets.broadcast? I tried this:

```
 function sendMessage(data){
   var socketIds = ['socketId1','socketId2'];
   sails.sockets.broadcast("room","event",data,socketIds);
   //sending data to ALL sockets in the room :/
 }
```

but it doesn't work.

I need know this because I need omit the sockets which belong to the same session. (example: session of user in computer browser and android browser)

somebody help?

Comment: What's exactly not working?

Comment: ignore the sockets that are in the array socketsIds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing built-in that will do this for you, but `broadcast` is just a wrapper around `emit` anyway, so you can just roll your own by getting all of the socket IDs in the room you want to broadcast to, and omitting the IDs in your array.

```
// Get all the IDs of the sockets subscribed to "room"
var socketIds = sails.sockets.subscribers("room");
// Remove the IDs you want to omit
socketIds = _.difference(socketIds, ['socketId1','socketId2']);
// Emit your event to the rest!
sails.sockets.emit(socketIds, "event", data);
```